# How can I parse SOAP response that contains complextype in iOS, with Swift?

Tags: php, ios, swift, web-services, soap

I write this soap web service in PHP, using NuSOAP library

```
require_once "nusoap/lib/nusoap.php";

$userBookServer = new nusoap_server();
$userBookServer->configureWSDL('recuperaLibri', 'urn:retrieveBooks');
$userBookServer->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';

$userBookServer->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Book',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'Titolo' => array('name' => 'Titolo', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'Autore'=> array('name' => 'Autore', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
    )

);

$userBookServer->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'userBook',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(
        array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType', 'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Book[]')
    ),
    'tns:Book'
);

$userBookServer->register("recuperaLibri", array('id_unico' => 'xsd:string'),
    array('return' => 'tns:userBook'),'urn:recuperaLibri', 'urn:retrieveBooks#recuperaLibri','rpc','encoded');


/**
 * @param $uid
 */

function recuperaLibri($uid){

    require_once "DataStorage_utilities/DataManager.php";

    $response = array();
    //$response['userBook'] = array();

    $db = new DataManager();
    $userBooks = $db->getUserBook($uid);

    while($userBook = $userBooks->fetch_assoc()){

        //crea un array temporaneo
        $tmp = array();

        $tmp[0]['Titolo'] = $userBook[0]['Titolo'];
        $tmp[0]['Autore'] = $userBook[0]['Autore'];

        //inserisce l'array temporaneo nell'array response
        //array_push($response['userBook'], $tmp);
        array_push($response, $tmp);

    }

    //return json_encode($response);
    return $response;

}

$userBookServer->service(file_get_contents('php://input'));
exit();
```

The function `recuperaLibri` returns an array that contains the user books. This array must be shown in UITableView. Something like this:

[image]

This is SOAP response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-  ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:retrieveBooks">    
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:recuperaLibriResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:recuperaLibri">
     <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:Book[0]"/>
  </ns1:recuperaLibriResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I write the client of service in Swift 3 using SOAPEngine.

```
import UIKit

//class LibriTableViewController: UITableViewController, XMLParserDelegate{
class LibriTableViewController: UITableViewController{

    var elements: NSArray = NSArray()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let userID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID")

        let soapMessageRequest = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:urn='urn:recuperaLibri'><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><urn:recuperaLibri soapenv:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'><id_unico xsi:type='xsd:string'>userID</id_unico></urn:recuperaLibri></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"

        let soap = SOAPEngine()
        soap.actionNamespaceSlash = true
        soap.envelope = soapMessageRequest
        soap.setValue("\(userID)", forKey: "userID")
        soap.requestWSDL("http://localhost:8090/StudentPORT_WS/LibriUtenteService.php?wsdl", operation: "recuperaLibri" ,
                         completeWithDictionary: {(statusCode: Int?, dict: [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Void in

                            let book:NSDictionary = dict! as NSDictionary
                            self.elements = book["Book"] as! NSArray
                            self.tableView?.reloadData()


        }) { (error:Error?) -> Void in

            print(error)

        }



    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.elements.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:LibriUtenteTableViewCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellBookId", for: indexPath) as? LibriUtenteTableViewCell)!
        if cell == nil {

            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellBookId") as! LibriUtenteTableViewCell
        }

        let bookRow:NSDictionary = self.elements[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

        let titolo:String = bookRow["Titolo"] as! String
        let autore:String = bookRow["Autore"] as! String

        cell.titoloLabel.text = String(format: "%@", titolo)
        cell.autoreLabel.text = String(format: "%@", autore)

        return cell


    }



}
```

But when the application is running and I try to see the table, I found this message in XCode:

```
2017-02-08 22:49:30.421 StudentPORT[2818:382651] Initializing SOAPEngine v.1.31
2017-02-08 22:49:30.517 StudentPORT[2818:382651] SOAPEngine Server response: (null)
Optional(Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)")
```

How can I get the array from SOAP response and display it properly??

Comment: you probably need to use the IP address of the machine where the service is running instead of localhost.  Localhost in this context is the iPhone .

Comment: This service running in localhost, not in other machine.

Comment: yes, but your iPhone or simulator is another machine. If you use localhost, it would assume that the service is running on the iPhone. Is your service running on the iPhone?

Comment: No, this service running in Apache, no in simulator.

Comment: please use the IP address of the Apache server and you will find out :D

Comment: I tried to change localhost:8090 in 127.0.0.1:8090 or use 192.168... or www.example.com:80 but doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

soap.envelope must only contain the additional namespace, like below:

```
soap.envelope = "xmlns:com1='http://www.rbm.com.co/esb/comercio/'"
```

when using the method named requestWSDL this is not optimized, very slow, instead you can use the optimization that descripted here : https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine#optimizations